# Generating Java JNI Header

Tags: java, header, java-native-interface

All I'm trying to do is generate a JNI Header file using JDK Javah.exe program, but no matter what I try I keep getting the error message "Error: could not find class file for 'ddg.ndkTest.NativeLib'" (where ddg.ndkTest is the namespace and NativeLib is the java class file). Also, please note that to simplify the process further, I've copied my entire Android project to the Java directory.

I've tried the following commands, none of which have worked:

- `javah -jni ddg.ndkTest.NativeLib`
- `javah -verbose -jni -classpath \NDKTest\bin\classes ddg.ndkTest.NativeLib`
- `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin>javah.exe -jni -classpath \NDKTest\bin\classes\ ddg.ndkTest.NativeLib`

If my package is called; "ddg.ndkTest", and my class is; "NativeLib.java", and my classpath above is correct. What should I write in my command window?

Comment: does the directory \ndktest\bin\classes\ddg\ndkTest exist? that's what your second attempt is looking for.

Comment: Yes I am able to view the entire directory and see the actual NativeLib.class file where i was pointing to, making it even more frustrating.

Comment: "to simplify the process further, I've copied my entire Android project to the Java directory": what makes you think that will simplify anything? Don't make the mistake of thinking that arbitrary actions will make anything simpler. They won't. Stop guessing and start analyzing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

1. Build your classes first
2. Change directory down to `\NDKTest\bin\classes\`
3. Run `javah ddg.ndkTest.NativeLib`

Comment: This comment isn't actual for Java 9+.

Answer (score 25):

### Update for java >= Java9

Since `Java9` the command `javah` has been flagged with a `deprecation warning` and starting from `Java10` it has been deleted from the JDK since its functionalities are now included in the `javac` command.

So in order **to do the same from Java9 you should run:**
`javac -h . NativeLib.java`

*Note I am assuming you are in the correct directory*

The main difference besides the command is that now the JNI header creation is targeting the source code in the `.java` file and not the compiled `.class`

> **-h *directory***
> Specifies where to place generated native header files.
>
> When you specify this option, a native header file is generated for each class that contains native methods or that has one or more constants annotated with the java.lang.annotation.Native annotation. If the class is part of a package, then the compiler puts the native header file in a subdirectory that reflects the package name and creates directories as needed.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9

Comment: This command javac -h . NativeLib.java only generates .class file, not c header file. can you help? JDK 17.

Comment: Solved. Ran the command twice, first generated the class file and second generated the header file.

Answer (score 1):

javah is looking for `NativeLib.class`, not the source code. So you should point it to where your compiled classes are, wherever it is. Even if not in `NDKTest/Bin/Classes` where you apparently expect it.

Answer (score 0):

@rakwaht & @Sergey naswers i good.

```
javac -h . -cp ".;lib/*" MyCppNI.java
```

Additioaly i faced:

1. List item ext ".java" is mandatory
2. "-o" output. Options does not work for javac (but i used it for javah)